# Tree view row activated with ONE click

Tags: python, signals, glade

I am creating a graphical interface with glade that contents a treeview.

I want to have a button that is initially enabled by doing a simple click on a row of the treeview.

I am using `row-activated`, but when I activate a row for the first time I have to double click the row.

Which signal should I use to detect the click to activate the row with a single click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GtkTreeView as an `activate-on-single-click` property.

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView--activate-on-single-click

Comment: Hi, I think you are right. But I couldn't find anything about how to do it in Python. Finally, I decided to use the cursor-changed signal of the TreeView with Glade... And it worked with one click!

Comment: `your_treeview.props.activate_on_single_click = True`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for future reference, for Python3 and Gtk3 what worked for me was:

    `myTree.set_property('activate-on-single-click', True)`